# Could not resolve repository metadata for rest

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-rest, embedded-tomcat-8

I want to make Spring Boot service in which I can get all table values, or values with appropriate id address from SQL server database, for this reason, I have used:

- CrudReposiotry
- application.properties with server configuration
- RestController
- SpringBootApplication with it's embedded Tomcat

Here is my repository interface:

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import  ge.sda.spring.HoliDay.Data.*;

@Repository
public interface DayRepository extends CrudRepository<DayEntity, Integer> {

}
```

Here is my service:

```
@Service
public class CalculateHoliDayService {
@Autowired
public DayRepository repository;

public DayEntity getDayByID(Integer  Id) {
    return repository.findOne(Id);
}

public List<DayEntity> getAllDay(){
    List<DayEntity>docs=new ArrayList<DayEntity>();
      repository.findAll().forEach(docs::add);
        return  docs;
}

}
```

Here is my controller:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import ge.sda.spring.HoliDay.Data.DayEntity;
import ge.sda.spring.HoliDayService.CalculateHoliDayService ;


   @RestController
   @RequestMapping("/profile/rest") 
    public class DayController {

    @Autowired
    public  CalculateHoliDayService  DayService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/all")
    public List<DayEntity> getAllDocument() {
        return DayService.getAllDay();
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/{id}")
    public DayEntity getDocument(@PathVariable Integer Id) {
        return DayService.getHoliDayByID(Id);
    }
    }
```

Here is application.properties:

```
# Server server.port=9010 spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://url;    servername=server;databaseName=Days
spring.datasource.username=user spring.datasource.password=*****
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
# Logging logging.level.com.bytestree.restful=DEBUG
```

Application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

here  is  my  pom:

```
 <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
          <jvmArguments>
            -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005
          </jvmArguments>
        </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

But when I start spring boot application and try this URL:
http://localhost:9010/profile/rest/2

I got this error:

[image]

> 2018-03-26 15:44:02.416 ERROR 612 --- [nio-9010-exec-6]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
>   servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
>   [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve repository
>   metadata for all.] with root cause
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve repository
>   metadata for all.     at
>   org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.ResourceMetadataHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(ResourceMetadataHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java:97)
>   ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.6.6.RELEASE.jar:na]   at
>   org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RootResourceInformationHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(RootResourceInformationHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java:83)
>   ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.6.6.RELEASE.jar:na]   at
>   org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RootResourceInformationHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(RootResourceInformationHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java:40)
>   ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.6.6.RELEASE.jar:na]   at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:158)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.8.0_151]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.8.0_151]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown
>   Source) [na:1.8.0_151]

**what should I change to make this service work?**

Comment: Where is your controller for /profile/rest/2?

Comment: hi  on DayController i  have  annotation RequestMapping("/rest")  the  rest  code  is  in my  DayController class

Comment: Can you provide full class for profile/rest/2 ?

Comment: i  have  added  full  class example in    main  question

Comment: change to  @RequestMapping(value="/{id}")
    public DayEntity getDocument(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        return DayService.getHoliDayByID(id);
    }

Comment: need lowercase id, I think  or add name @PathVariable("Id") Integer Id

Comment: and also use lowercase for method arguments and instance variables if you are writing in JAVA

Comment: i  have  replaced  Id  with  lowercase  id but  nothing  has  changed  i  will add  my  pom file  into main question

Comment: Please check your post again, You are calling `DayEntity` but you posted here `HolidayEntity` same for Service class `CalculateHoliDayService `

Comment: Please post these classes... `DayController.java`
`CalculateHoliDayService.java`
`DayEntity.java`
`DayRepository.java`

Comment: I  will  add  them in main  question

Comment: Remove `@Repository` annotation from `DayRepository.java` and just try to run. we will see what happening..

Comment: i  have  same Could not resolve repository metadata

Comment: Its 404 so you have invalid mappings - it would be 500 if it would be caused by exception. Also you have cut the most interesting part of the exception quoting: *with root cause...* the cause is the most interesting part, not what happened later ;)

Comment: now   when i   have  removed @Reposiotry   annotation i   got 505  error  also  i  have  added  complete error  code in main  question

Comment: but  normally  i  have  404  error

Comment: Does it work if you name the PathVariable the same as the parameter of your method?

Comment: Can't  work  becaus  crudReposiotry  method  findone can  only  take  number  variables

Comment: I  got  what  you  mean  and  i  have  also  replace   id  variable  name  with getHolyDay  but  this  couldn't  change  anythinh

Comment: By  the  way  do  you  know  what  is  profile  inside   tomcat?

Comment: is  it  possible  that  embedded  tomcat  in my  spring  boot  application can  cause  runtime  errors?

Comment: have you tried to set @PathVariable("id")?

Comment: Also set the parameter to String and convert it then to an Integer afterwards.

Comment: I  have  tried  this   but  when i  run  this  program  i  got  this  404 error